# Findbugs maven strange warning

Tags: java, maven, findbugs, spotbugs

I am using maven 3.5.2 and the following configuration of findbugs maven plugin:

```
 <!-- Findbugs checks -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${findbugs.maven.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <effort>Max</effort>
      <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-filter.xml</excludeFilterFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Where findbugs-filter.xml contains:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Bug code="" category="EXPERIMENTAL" />
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

and I am getting the following warning:

```
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.4:findbugs (findbugs) @ api ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
[java] Dub 11, 2018 4:30:38 ODP. java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
[java] WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

Should I worry or ignore it ?

Comment: Quick note: You should be using the SpotBugs Maven plugin. FindBugs is no longer updated: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.